# Deploy tensorflow model to world

Tags: tensorflow, deployment, model, google-cloud-platform

I want to deploy my tensorflow model to real world. i had already been used the REST method by using FLASK to develop the model deployment in localhost (without tensorflow-serving). I find that google-cloud and amazon provide the model deployment server. Other than google and amazon, is there other way to deploy my model? Is it able to use normal web host server to deploy model??

Comment: Yes, you can use [TensorFlow Serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/) on any host you want, or write your own API and use regular TensorFlow to run the inference, again on any host. The necessary processing power and availability of the host is obviously another matter.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a docker container from your flask app. Once you have the docker container, you can deploy it as a 'normal' app to any cloud provider you want(aws ec2, digitalocean, etc).

One thing you want to make sure included in your flask app is to have all of the dependencies and all of your preprocessing code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Given that you have already your project using Flask, you can deploy using [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python). You can connect it to Github and deploy quite easily. The only important thing is to deploy a Procfile. You can check out the documentation on how to do it. There is also a tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@limkenghin/deploying-tensorflow-2-0-model-on-heroku-1b5cd49f8a2)